# Access violation reading location 0x00000000 in binary search tree

Tags: c++, access-violation

Just showing how the node of the binary tree looks like. I'm not sure what is wrong but I have a feeling it has something to do with the function being private. How I can compare the private data so I can see if the value I am looking for is inside that node?

```
    class binarytree
    {
    private:
        class node
        {
        public:

            int data;
            node * left;
            node * right;

            node (int x)
            {
                data = x;
                left=NULL;
                right=NULL;
            }


        };

    node * root;
```

This is how I insert the node

```
    void insert(int x, node * &r)
        {
            if(r==NULL)
            {
                r= new node(x);
            }

            else
    {
        if(x < r->data)
        {
            //insert left
            insert(x, r->left);
        }

        else
        {
            //insert right
            insert(x, r->right);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the part of the code that gives me trouble when I try to compare x to r->data the program crashes and gives me the error message " Access violation reading location 0x00000000"

```
void remove(int x, node * &r)
{

    if(x == r->data)
    {
        if(r->right == NULL && r->left == NULL)
        {

            r = NULL;

        }

        else if(r->right == NULL && r->left != NULL)
        {
            r = r->left;

        }

        else if(r->right != NULL && r->left == NULL)
        {
            r = r->right;
        }

        else
        {
            node * temp;
            temp =r;
            r = r->left;
            while(r->right != NULL)
            {
                r = r->right;
            }

            r->right = temp->right;
            delete temp;
        }
    }

    else if ( x < r->data)
    {

        remove(x, r->left);

    }

    else if (x > r->data)
    {
        remove(x , r->left);
    }


}
```

This is where the functions are publicly. Then I call the private functions so I can manipulate the private tree.

```
public:

    binarytree()
    {
    root =  NULL;
    }

    ~binarytree()
    {
    //tooo: write this
    }

//return true if empty, false if not
    bool empty()
    {}


    void insert(int x)
    {
    insert(x, root);

    }




    void remove(int x)
    {
        remove(x,root);

    }

};
```

EDIT: Here is another function of the program that works but might be causing r to point to NULL.

```
    int extractMin(node * &r)
{

    if(r->left == NULL)
    {
        if(r->right == NULL)
        {

            return r->data;

        }

        else
        {
            int x = r->data;
            r = r->right;
            return x;

        }
    }

    else
    {

        return extractMin(r->left);

    }
}
```

Here is the new function to check to see if r is NULL

```
    void remove(int x, node * &r)
{
    if(r == NULL)
    {
        cout<<"why am I null?"<<endl;
    }

    else
    {
        if(x == r->data)
        {
            if(r->right == NULL && r->left == NULL)
            {

                r = NULL;

            }

            else if(r->right == NULL && r->left != NULL)
            {
                r = r->left;

            }

            else if(r->right != NULL && r->left == NULL)
            {
                r = r->right;
            }

            else
            {
                node * temp;
                temp =r;
                r = r->left;
                while(r->right != NULL)
                {
                    r = r->right;
                }

                r->right = temp->right;
                delete temp;
            }
        }

        else if ( x < r->data)
        {

            remove(x, r->left);

        }

        else if (x > r->data)
        {
            remove(x , r->left);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: TL;DR (see http://sscce.org). Anyway, "Access violation reading location 0x00000000" is obviously a NULL-pointer dereference.

Comment: Run your program in a debugger, and step through the `insert` function line by line to make sure it's working properly. If it does then step through the `remove` function line by line.

Comment: It seems that in your `remove` function you need to check if `r` is not `NULL`... and `return` immediatly if it is... Anyway as Joachim says, use a debugger when you have this kind of problem.

Answer (score 2):

you should always check for `NULL` before trying to get to the inner members:

```
void remove(int x, node * &r)
{
    if(r != NULL)
    {
       // Your code
    }
}
```

you call to remove with `r` as `NULL` and then try to check `r.Left`. then here you have access violation

also i must ask, did any if this worked for you? specifically `insert` wont work this way.
try

```
    void insert(int x, node * &r)
    {
        if(r==NULL)
        {
            r= new node(x);
        }
        else
        {
            if(x < r->data)
            {
                if(r->left != NULL)
                {
                   //insert left
                   insert(x, r->left);
                }
                else
                {
                    r->left = new node(x);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(r->right != NULL)
                {
                   //insert right
                   insert(x, r->right);
                }
                else
                {
                    r->left = new node(x);
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Okay I checked for NULL and it shows that r == NULL. How is my root NULL?

Comment: @user2782774 As I tell you in my answer: you set it NULL in the constructor so if you call remove on it before you call  isnert you haven't changed it. Or if you call remove if there is no node left, then you also put it to NULL this could be because of a wrong loop index or something... do you even udnerstand you own code?

Comment: @user2782774 also, i don't think your insert method works properly

Comment: yes everything in the code works fine besides the remove function. I have a public void function named "insert" that has an int parameter.

Comment: @user2782774 i know, but if everything worked fine you wouldn't have a NULL as root.... try to insert and print some items...

Answer (score 0):

Well it the error says, r is pointing to NULL when you try to derefference it.
So you have to make sure when you assign memmory to r it doesn't return NULL.

```
binarytree()
{
    root =  NULL;
}

void remove(int x)
{
    remove(x,root);

}
```

In your case you are trying to derefference NULL (as the error says) This happens in your code when you are calling a remove before you have called an insert.
You simply should check at the beginning of remove for r isn't pointing to NULL.
Or even better, make sure you won't parse in r when its NULL.

Answer (score 0):

`r` is null somehow. You need to check if the `r` passed in is `NULL`, or check if the `root` is non-null, and call `remove` on children only if they exist.

Comment: I checked and R is indeed NULL but I dont know how that is possible when there are items in the tree.

Comment: @user2782774 you are calling remove on children without checking, thats how

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing `x` to the `root`. When your tree is empty, `root == nullptr`. You should check to see if `r == nullptr` first, as in:

```
bool remove(int x, node * &r) {
   if(!r) {
      return false; // Indicate whether removal succeeded
   }

   //... etc.
}
```